# Can I visualize (but not simulate) using drake?

Tags: drake, meshcat

I want to visualize a path without simulating, i.e. solving forward in time, or detecting collisions, etc; I just want it to draw on the screen. I realize meshcat does this on its own, and I don't *need* `drake` for that, but `drake` makes importing my robot so easy.

Ideally, I'm looking for an attribute that can give me a `meshcat.visualizer.Visualizer` object with my robot in it. I already have code that uses the meshcat `Animation` class to draw, I just need some help finding the `meshcat.visualizer.Visualizer` object.

Is there anything that exposes this?

I tried looking around in documentation to see if anything exposes this attribute, or if anything could be used to replace it. Everything I've found so far is of class `pydrake.geometry.MeshcatVisualizer` or `pydrake.visualization.ModelVisualizer`, neither of which are the "raw" `meshcat.visualizer.Visualizer`.

I did also consider attaching a fake time to the whole thing, and then doing some kind of velocity control, and turn off collisions. I think `pydrake.geometry.MeshcatVisualizer` is probably pretty well set up for that, and I could probably just use `StartRecording()`, maybe, but it feels bad to attach time to something that doesn't have a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood correctly, I have a method which accomplishes roughly this available [here](https://manipulation.mit.edu/python/meshcat_utils.html#manipulation.meshcat_utils.PublishPositionTrajectory).

The implementation is effectively what you suggested:

```
    plant_context = plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)
    visualizer_context = visualizer.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)

    visualizer.StartRecording(False)

    for t in np.append(
        np.arange(trajectory.start_time(), trajectory.end_time(), time_step),
        trajectory.end_time(),
    ):
        root_context.SetTime(t)
        plant.SetPositions(plant_context, trajectory.value(t))
        visualizer.ForcedPublish(visualizer_context)

    visualizer.StopRecording()
    visualizer.PublishRecording()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried the code snippet here, and it just worked. Thanks!

Comment: Will check out `PublishPositionTrajectory()` on the next refactor.